# Install rpy2 using pip install xx.whl on windows 10

Tags: python, r, pip, rpy2, jupyter-notebook

I want to use *rpy2* library on my labtop. But I have failed to installed this whole morning.

A few question have posted here. Any advice would be appreciate!

#### Attempt 1

Using `pip install rpy2`. The result shows like:

```
 Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\hyf\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gkdpb0\rpy2\
```

#### Attempt 2

Then, I read some post. And someone told that with *.whl* format package can solve the problem.  SO: 
Using `pip install rpy2-2.7.8-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` to install the package which I downloaded. Failed with:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Program\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\rpy2\\rinterface\\_rinterface.pyd'
```

#### Attempt 3

Using`conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/joshadel rpy2`, the rpy2 package can be installed.

But when I call it in ipython notebook like this:

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import r
```

The result shows the error:

```
RuntimeError: R_HOME not defined.
```

But I have added the environment variables into system variables like this:

```
R_HOME:D:\Program\R\bin\x64
R_User:D:\Program\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\rpy2
```

I'm using Anaconda with Python2.7 kernel and R 3.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `R_HOME` should refer to the root R directory, from the `__init__` file, there appears these lines

```
# Load the R dll using the explicit path
R_DLL_DIRS = ('bin', 'lib')
# Try dirs from R_DLL_DIRS
for r_dir in R_DLL_DIRS:
    Rlib = os.path.join(R_HOME, r_dir, _win_bindir, 'R.dll')
```

where `_win_bindir` will refer to x64 or the 32-bit version.  So, from a shell (or more permanently change in the system settings), you can set the environment variable as

```
set R_HOME=D:\Program\R
```

and try python (from that shell!).